# Django get FK through a selector function

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 models:

```
class A:
start_date=DateField
end_date=DateField
... 
@property
def is_valid():
    if self.start_date is not None and self.end_date is not None:
            return self.start_date <= get_now().date() <= self.end_date
    elif (self.start_date is None or self.start_date <= get_now.date()) and self.end_date is None:
            return True

class B:
a = ManyToMany(A)

class C:
b = ForeignKey(B)
```

and a selector function `get_valid_a's` that returns all valid instances of `class A` given a single `class B`

Selector function:

```
def get_valid_a's(B):
    return B.A.filter((
            Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) &  
    Q(end_date__gte=get_now().date())) | (
            Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) & 
    Q(end_date__isnull=True)) | (
            Q(start_date__isnull=True) & Q(end_date__isnull=True))
        )
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
C_with_valid_A = C.objects.filter(
    d_pk=d_pk, 
    b__a__isnull=False,
   <here I am lookig to do something like: b__a__in=get_valid_a's(b=b)
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the code for the is_valid property and the relevant fields? Would be a lot easier if this property could also be calculated in an annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read some of the Django documentation and found a really useful DB-level function that can be used in such cases - [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries)

The fetching query looks like this

```
C_with_valid_A = C.objects.annotate(
    has_valid_As=Exists(
    A.objects.filter((
            Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) &  
    Q(end_date__gte=get_now().date())) | (
            Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) & 
    Q(end_date__isnull=True)) | (
            Q(start_date__isnull=True) & Q(end_date__isnull=True)), 
    Bs=OuterRef('b')
    )).filter(has_valid_As=True,d=d_pk)
```

For Django >= 3.0 the same query can be written as

```
C_with_valid_A = C.objects.filter(
    Exists(
    A.objects.filter((
            Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) &  
    Q(end_date__gte=get_now().date())) | (
            Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) & 
    Q(end_date__isnull=True)) | (
            Q(start_date__isnull=True) & Q(end_date__isnull=True)), 
    Bs=OuterRef('b'),
    d=d_pk
))
```

Which essentially does the same as the first query underneath. In my understanding, [`OuterRef`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#referencing-columns-from-the-outer-queryset) represents the relation between model C to model B.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/) to A and add a method to that manager that filters by valid results. You can always just make this a classmethod for a quick win

(I've just pasted the query as it's almost impossible to verify/parse :D)

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def get_valid(cls):
        return cls.objects.filter((
            Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) & Q(end_date__gte=get_now().date())) | (
        Q(start_date__lte=get_now().date()) & 
Q(end_date__isnull=True)) | (
        Q(start_date__isnull=True) & Q(end_date__isnull=True)))
```

Then you can use this method in your other queries

```
C_with_valid_A = C.objects.filter(
    d_pk=d_pk,
    b__a__in=A.get_valid()
)
```

Comment: Great solution dude, appreciate it!

Comment: What would happen if there are millions of instances of class A? Would that means that on the SQL level there would be millions of searches as in `where id in ...`?

Comment: @A.P. it really depends on the DB you are using, MySQL performs absolutely terribly when it comes to subqueries but PostgreSQL will handle them just fine. Which DB are you using?

Comment: I am using PSQL. Can you please elaborate a bit more on "will handle them just fine"

Comment: I mean the query should not perform significantly worse than one that used joins instead of a subquery